# mail command does not return

Tags: email, sendmail, ssmtp

On Ubuntu 13.04 I have been trying to send emails from the command line but the mail command will not return. I am running these from inside a putty terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
sudo apt-get install sendemail
echo "test message" | sendmail -s 'test subject' me@gmail.com
```

or

```
sendmail -s "test" me@gmail.com < out
```

both hange so the the cursor does not return to the command prompt. I have also tried other variations using `mail`,`ssmtp`, and `postfix` (also installed them all). They all do the same thing. For `ssmtp` I added config like this:

```
root=aaaa@gmail.com 
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465 
rewriteDomain=gmail.com 
AuthUser=aaaa
AuthPass=pass
FromLineOverride=YES
```

Comment: Which package does provide your `sendmail`? `dpkg -S \`which sendmail\``

Comment: `dpkg -S \`which sendmail\`` => `ssmtp: /usr/sbin/sendmail`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for 12.04 and I'm sure they haven't changed the package that much

```
apt-get install bsd-mailx
```

Then you can send mail like

```
echo "hi there" | mail -s "subject here" me@gmail.com
```

Comment: Same result, also tried running with bsd-mailx to ensure I was running that version. No luck.

Comment: you'd have to post your parts of your mail.log to see if there is a reason there

Comment: `mail -v` returns `no mail for username` and the mail.log has `sSMTP[14573]: Unable to locate mail\n sSMTP[14573]: Cannot open mail:25`

Comment: you need to show your /var/log/mail.log entries is what i meant

Answer (score 0):

Try the collowing test commands:

```
(echo "subject: test"; echo) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i me@gmail.com
(echo "subject: test"; echo) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -v -i me@gmail.com
```